# R dynamic logical condition (predicate)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I have a function that build a logical condition dynamically according to parameter (that determines the predicate length).
Here's the code:

```
predicate <- function(pred.size){

predicate.result <- ""

for(s in 1:pred.size){

predicate.result <- paste (predicate.result,data.clean.eval[j,top.pred.size.predictions[[s]][1]] , " == TRUE ", sep = " ")
if (!s==pred.size) predicate.result <- paste (predicate.result, " OR ")
}

if (paste(predicate.result)) return TRUE else RETURN FALSE
}
```

however, pred.result return a string:

> predicate.result
>   [1] " FALSE  == TRUE   OR  FALSE  == TRUE "
>   and when coming to test the condition
>   if (paste(predicate.result)) return TRUE else RETURN FALSE
>   R return error:
>   Error: unexpected numeric constant in "if (paste(predicate.result)) return TRUE"

any idea how to test that predicate and make this function return TRUE/FALSE ?

Comment: You have several functions in there that are not in the base package. Please give their package source.  Now, there's a fundamental error: `paste` does not return a value which can be coerced to `logical`, so your last `if` condition will fail with error.  What do you want to test `predicate.result` for?

Comment: predicate.result is a string which represents a logical predicate consists of s arguments of the form: a1 == TRUE OR a2 == TRUE ... and so on - s times. each of these arguments is either TRUE or FALSE. The final test : "if (paste(predicate.result)) return TRUE else RETURN FALSE" is meant to evaluate the whole predicate. Hope I made my self clear. Regarding the apckages, which functions do you refer to as not belong to the base package ?

Comment: I think question is how to coerce string to logcial. I tried using as.logical(), but it returned NA

Comment: Maybe what you want is `if(length(predicate.result) > 0 ) ...`  . That lets you see if your output essentially exists or not